# Generating vectors from mixture normal distribution

Tags: matlab, random, distribution, normal-distribution, mixture

I would have function to generating vectors from mixture normal distribution. Firstly I have done function, to generating vectors from `N(mu, Sigma)` :

```
function [X] = BSXgen(N,d,mu,sigma)
    A = chol(sigma);
    X = bsxfun(@plus, mu, A'*randn(d,N));
end
```

I can use it by  `BSXgen(10,2,[0;0],diag([1 1]))` to generate `10` vectors from two-dimensional space.

Next, I would generating data from mixture Normal distribution. What I'm doing:

```
N=5000; %number of vectors
d=2; %dimension of space
K=5; %number of mixtures
p=0.2*ones(1,K); %probability of every mixture - in this case p1=...=p5=0.2

mu = [ [2;2] [4;1] [2;8] [4;6] [8;2]] %matrix with mu parameters for every mixture

SIGMA = diag([0.5 0.5]); %in this case - for every mixture we will have the same SIGMA matrix

U = unifrnd(0,1,1,N); %Random variable from U(0,1)

%Generating vectors from mixture
X = [];
for i=1:K
    m = size(U(U<sum(p([1:i])) & U>= sum(p([1:i-1]))));
    X = [X BSXgen(m(2),d,mu(:,i),SIGMA)];
end

%Plotting vectors
X=X';
scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),3,'fill')
```

Am I right? Am I generating really data from mixture? I'm not sure so I will be really grateful for any opinion.

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you asking whether `BSXgen()` is generating random data represented as a mixture? Which variable are you unsure of and what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: I'm not sure, Am I generating data from mixture? And is maybe better (faster) way to generate it?

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way but how do you expect anyone to answer your question if you don't know for yourself what you are asking? Please modify the question and be more specific. Explain which variable you are unsure of, include the input and the output.This link might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve